# Libgdx multiple textures in one sprite

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm working for a game and got into this point: I would like to have 2 textures in a single sprite, is that possible?

I mean: I need one to be set in a specific angle, and the other one to be rotating continuously. I've been looking on the internet but found nothing related.

Or.. is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Sprite` inherits from a `TextureRegion`.
This is the definition of `TextureRegion`:

> Defines a rectangular area of a texture.

So a `Sprite` really is just a piece of Texture, that means you can only transform a Sprite as a whole.

If you want to wrap multiple Sprites into a single class, I suggest using [Scene2D](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d). You could draw two sprites in `Actor.draw()`:

```
public void draw() {
    sprite1.draw();
    sprite1.rotate(…);
    …
    sprite2.draw();
    …
}
```

The actor is then added to a `Stage`

```
stage.addActor(actor);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Sprite` is a `TextureRegion` that holds geometry, color, and other texture information for drawing so you can't keep multiple Texture in a Sprite and used all for drawing.

So use 1<sup>st</sup> if you're not using [scene2d](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d) else go with  2<sup>nd</sup> or 3<sup>rd</sup> option.

1. Create own class that contain two textureRegion and draw by yourself according to your requirement.
2. Create a `Group` as parent of your Images. Create different `Image`, add specific `Action`, `Color` and other property and then add to parent group.
3. Create a CompositeImage by inheriting `Image` class and add a new TextureRegion as property of your new Class. override `draw (Batch batch, float parentAlpha)` method and draw your added textureRegion.